# TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined, issue in passing props

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-props

I am passing the props from one component to another component which is located in another file. I have correctly created the constructors in both the component but still, I am fetting this error, as a newbie, I am not able to resolve this issue. I have searched on google and also on StackOverflow but I didn't get any satisfactory result.
App.js file:-

```js
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Menu from './component/MenuComponent';
import {DISHES} from './shared/dishes';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import {Navbar,NavbarBrand, Container} from 'reactstrap';
import { render } from 'react-dom';

//eslint-disable-next-line
class App extends Component{
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      dishes:DISHES
    }
  }
  render() {
    return(
      <div className='App'>
        <Navbar dark color ="primary">
          <div className="Container">
            <NavbarBrand href="#">Saurav Pandey</NavbarBrand>
          </div>
        </Navbar>
        <Menu dishes={this.state.dishes} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Card, CardBody, CardText, CardTitle, CardImg, CardImgOverlay } from 'reactstrap';
class Menu extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state={
      selectedDish:null
    }
    console.log('Menu component constructor is invoked');
  }

  onDishSelect(dish){
    this.setState({selectedDish:dish});
  }

  renderDish(dish) {
    if(dish!=null) {
      return(
        <Card>
          <CardImg top src={dish.image} alt={dish.name} />
          <CardBody>
            <CardTitle>{dish.name}</CardTitle>
            <CardText>{dish.description}</CardText>
          </CardBody>
        </Card>
      );
    } else {
      return(
        <div>not found!</div>
      );
    }
  }

  render() {
    if(this.props.dishes) {
       const menu=this.props.dishes.map((dish) => {
         return(
           <div className="col-12 col-md-5 m-1">
             <Card key={dish.id} onClick={()=>this.onDishSelect(dish)}>
                <CardImg width="100%" src={dish.image} alt={dish.name}/>
                  <CardImgOverlay>
                    <CardTitle>
                      {dish.name}
                    </CardTitle>
                  </CardImgOverlay>
                </Card>
              </div>
            );
          });
        return(
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              {menu}
            </div>
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-10 md-2 mt-1">
                {this.renderDish(this.state.selectedDish)}
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        );
    } else {
      return(
        <div>
          not found
        </div>
      );
    }
  };
}

export default Menu;
```

The other rendering files are created properly in separate files.
The dishes is an array and it looks like:-

```
 export const DISHES =
  [
        {
        id: 0,
        name:'Uthappizza',
        image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        label:'Hot',
        price:'4.99',
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
]
```

Comment: How does `dishes` actually look like? Is it an array

Comment: `if(!this.props.dishes)` here you want to `map` over `dishes` if it doesn't exist.

Comment: what does your DISHES look like it would be more helpful if you could add `'./shared/dishes';` to the question

Comment: I have updated the dishes file also. I have tried an if and else statement because just to check the rest of the code is correct or not.

Comment: @BeHappy I have updated this part also. I think that I am getting this error because here the value of props is NULL. I didn't understand why this issue happens instead of creating the correct constructors.

Comment: Can you make sure that you are using Menu on in the above component and nowhere else where you do not pass dishes prop

Comment: If it is `NULL` the `map` won't invoke.

Comment: @ShubhamKhatri yes, I have only used in the above component. The whole code has only two components. There is some issue in props creation and its use, but I am not able to detect it.

Comment: @BeHappy Yes, but I want to know why it ```this.props.dishes``` is NULL, because I pass the value of dishes in the Menu component.

Comment: It is good to create codesandbox to reproduce issue.

Comment: @BeHappy yes it works on code sandbox, but  why it shows error in vs code and chrome.

Comment: I see your `dishes` file, you missed `]` at end.

Answer (score 0):

I see your `DISHES` structure is not correct.

```
export const DISHES =
  [
        {
        id: 0,
        name:'Uthappizza',
        image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        label:'Hot',
        price:'4.99',
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
]
```

should look like this

```
export const DISHES =
  [
        {
        id: 0,
        name:'Uthappizza',
        image: 'assets/images/uthappizza.png',
        category: 'mains',
        label:'Hot',
        price:'4.99',
        description:'A unique combination of Indian Uthappam (pancake) and Italian pizza, topped with Cerignola olives, ripe vine cherry tomatoes, Vidalia onion, Guntur chillies and Buffalo Paneer.',
        comments: [
            {
            id: 0,
            rating: 5,
            comment: "Imagine all the eatables, living in conFusion!",
            author: "John Lemon",
            date: "2012-10-16T17:57:28.556094Z"
            },
            {
            id: 1,
            rating: 4,
            comment: "Sends anyone to heaven, I wish I could get my mother-in-law to eat it!",
            author: "Paul McVites",
            date: "2014-09-05T17:57:28.556094Z"
            }
       ]
   }
]
```

I surely think its that structure causing the issue, you are missing some brackets.

Comment: Thanks, @Piyush Rana for pointing out, but I would like to make sure that this is just a typo in StackOverflow otherwise my the DISHES is structured correctly, so the problem lies not with dishes.

Comment: Did you use console.log to check what's coming in `this.props.dishes`?

Comment: It's null that and the problem lies within that

Comment: Can you please provide the sandbox code for the following so that I can debug and see what's the problem.